# How to remove all positive numbers including 0 from multiple columns and retain the rows using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Supposing I have a df like this,

```
  column1   column2 column3 column4
0   ab         A      -1.0      32
1   ab         B     -99.0     NaN
2   ab         A      -4.0     NaN
3   ab         B       0.0      21
4   cd         A       NaN    -998
5   cd         B      12.0    -250
```

Is there a generic way to remove all positive numbers including 0 from the df without hardcoding the column names?

I have tried the following,

```
df.mask(df[['column3', 'column4']].ge(0))
```

I am able remove the positive numbers including 0 but at the same time loose the rest of the data for column1 and column2.

I want to retain the data for column1 and column2 while also removing/replacing it with NaN all positive numbers including 0 from the df

Final df,

```
  column1   column2 column3 column4
0   ab         A      -1.0     NaN
1   ab         B     -99.0     NaN
2   ab         A      -4.0     NaN
3   ab         B       NaN     NaN
4   cd         A       NaN    -998
5   cd         B       NaN    -250
```

Comment: You could loop over `df.columns`

Comment: So you want to replace all values >=0, with what exactly?

Comment: values with NaN's

Answer (score 3):

We can use `DataFrame.select_dtypes` with `DataFrame.mask` to only apply your logic on the numeric columns:

```
dfn = df.select_dtypes('number')
df[dfn.columns] = dfn.mask(dfn.ge(0))

  column1 column2  column3  column4
0      ab       A     -1.0      NaN
1      ab       B    -99.0      NaN
2      ab       A     -4.0      NaN
3      ab       B      NaN      NaN
4      cd       A      NaN   -998.0
5      cd       B      NaN   -250.0
```